# script to read a file and use the content to query against an api

Tags: shell, unix

I'm not familiar with unix scripting and trying to debug what the issue is behind the following script:

```
cat DataID.txt | awk -F"'" '{print $2}' | head | while read userid; do echo user=$userid has `curl -s "https://api.legacydata.com&filter_username=${userid}&group_by=date&filter_date_from=1585670400" | awk -F"[><]" '/TotalFound/{print $3}'` docs since 2020-04-01; done
```

OUTPUT:

```
user=CSM1DZAwbrIDg has 7 docs since 2020-04-01
user=YM0FftozblEBQ has 3 docs since 2020-04-01
user=F0UMyv5CSEnZQ has 1 docs since 2020-04-01
user=DWu15E7YmHffw has 54 docs since 2020-04-01
user=UC_6lzk1PyQk2 has 108 docs since 2020-04-01
user=UCcHndXwnifcQ has 1 docs since 2020-04-01
user=URd1FxA4pb0-A has 22 docs since 2020-04-01
user=KDTyF0LgQjqRQ has 3 docs since 2020-04-01
user=ASSG3vHTZqCSA has 3 docs since 2020-04-01
user=UC_CzhowCrkW has 7 docs since 2020-04-01
```

So this script is supposed to read from an input file and use the content which is a string id and query against an api. The results will be printed to the screen. The problem is that it is not reading the entire file and stops after a few rows but with no errors. Can someone assist with what could possible be the reason for this and how I should alter the script to fix this?

Comment: Thanks for your response; it worked. Unfortunately cannot credit you with the answer this way.

Comment: Of course. I just commented on what the problem was and voted to close as "solved in a manner unlikely to help future readers", since accidentally adding "head" is more of a typo/copy-paste issue and not a typical source of problems when querying APIs using file data.

Comment: greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to use of head command you are providing only 10 lines as input to your while loop. On removing head, it should take entire file.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Any chance you could assist with how to send the output to a text file?

Comment: Sure. At the end of command just add ">" to overwrite a file with your output or ">>" to append an existing file. If the file does not exist, in either case new file will be created. Your command will become :   `cat DataID.txt | awk -F"'" '{print $2}'  | while read userid; do echo user=$userid has \`curl -s "https://api.legacydata.com&filter_username=${userid}&group_by=date&filter_date_from=1585670400" | awk -F"[><]" '/TotalFound/{print $3}'\` docs since 2020-04-01; done  >> file.txt`